will "brown aluminum" drip-edge suffer galvanic corrosion if it rests against fascia made of copper-treated lumber?
Is "brown aluminum drip-edge" coated or painted to prevent galvanic corrosion if it rests upon fascia made from pressure-treated lumber (micronized copper azole)? If not, is there a type of paint that would provide long-term resistance to corrosion that could be put on the inside surface of the drip-edge?
P.S. I have construction screws that are coated specifically for use with treated lumber; wondering if flashing manufacturers are using something similar when their specs sheet says the drip-edge is "corrosion resistant".

Oh yes it will. Copper and aluminum do not like each other at all, even when it in the form of a preservative.
I had reason to place a pressure treated post against siding thinking the painted finish would protect the metal. It was not aluminum, but I know copper makes aluminum react badly. and the metal was starting to be eaten away after a few years. I needed to do something with that area, that was the only reason I was able to see this damage when I removed the post. I was going to set it back again.
To keep the aluminum for being damaged by the treated piece, use a narrow roll of peel and stick waterproofing membrane, like Vycor or other roll material. Some is advertised as a type of window flashing or door sill flashing. Many versions come in 4" wide rolls, which will be all the wider you will need.

I can't say for all cases, but I have some fencing made out of painted sheet aluminum that is nailed to pressure treated 4x4 fence posts.  It's been installed outside for well over 5 years and I don't see any corrosion on the aluminum itself.  There was some corrosion on the galvanized nails.
So, it appears that so long as there is a barrier (paint/plastic sheet) between the copper treated wood and the aluminum it will be fine.  The likely remedy for corrosion around any nails/screws/staples is to not use them (use construction adhesive).  If you must use nails/screws/stapes, put something like caulk in the holes to keep water and air out.
